# npm install oom when package-lock.json is

Tags: node.js, npm

The `npm install` stage in my application started failing with an out-of-memory error when there's no `package-lock.json` present after upgrading dependencies, node, and npm. The failing versions are:

```
node v18.19.1
npm 10.5.0
```

running on Ubuntu 23.10 with 8Gb of memory.

The `npm install` succeeds when the `package-lock.json` is present; however, without the file, it seems the resolving stage in the latest version is taking more memory than prior versions.

```
$ npm install
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
(⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠧ idealTree:@angular/core: sill placeDep ROOT zone.js@0.14.4 OK for: my-app@3.4.0 want: ^0.14.4
<--- Last few GCs --->

[6093:0x6643c70]    32888 ms: Scavenge 1987.5 (2035.9) -> 1985.7 (2035.4) MB, 7.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.704, current mu = 0.714) task; 
[6093:0x6643c70]    33552 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2064.0 (2110.8) -> 2058.5 (2095.6) MB, 455.9 / 0.1 ms  (+ 101.8 ms in 28 steps since start of marking, biggest step 8.6 ms, walltime since start of marking 575 ms) (average mu = 0.500, current mu = 0.301) 

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb95be0 node::Abort() [npm install]
 2: 0xa9a7f8  [npm install]
 3: 0xd6f5b0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [npm install]
 4: 0xd6f957 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [npm install]
 5: 0xf4ceb5  [npm install]
 6: 0xf5f38d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [npm install]
 7: 0xf39a7e v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [npm install]
 8: 0xf3ae47 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [npm install]
 9: 0xf1b3c0 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [npm install]
10: 0xf12e34 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawWithImmortalMap(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::Map, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [npm install]
11: 0xf150e8 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewRawOneByteString(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [npm install]
12: 0x1055349 v8::internal::JsonParser<unsigned short>::MakeString(v8::internal::JsonString const&, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [npm install]
13: 0x1057066 v8::internal::JsonParser<unsigned short>::ParseJsonValue() [npm install]
14: 0x1057b4f v8::internal::JsonParser<unsigned short>::ParseJson() [npm install]
15: 0xdf5213 v8::internal::Builtin_JsonParse(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [npm install]
16: 0x170e179  [npm install]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

You can reproduce with the following:

```
{
  "name": "npm-oom",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^8.1.1",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver-es": "^2.0.3",
    "cross-var": "^1.1.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^5.15.1",
    "file-saver-es": "^2.0.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "ng-storages": "^1.1.5",
    "npm": "^10.5.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.1",
    "reinstall": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^16.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^16.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^16.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^16.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^16.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.14",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.9"
  }
}
```

and

```
npm install -g npm@10.5.0; rm -rf node_modules/ package-lock.json; npm install --force
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be regression in the npm cli dependency resolution algorithm; I have opened a bug with npm:

https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/7276

This can be worked around by extending the default memory:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8000 $(which npm) install
```

or downgrade to `npm 10.3.0` or earlier; this problem first appeared in `npm 10.4.0` and is also present in the (current latest) `npm 10.5.0`.